# Cocoa - Is there any way to know when the dock is showing or hiding?

Tags: macos, cocoa, events, show-hide, dock

I'm developing a Mac OS application using Cocoa. I want to ask if there is any way to detect the visibility of Mac OS Dock (for ex: Does Cocoa fire an event when the dock is showing and hiding ?). I've been searching and still haven't found out any effective way to do this (Seems like Carbon does have this kind of event but Cocoa does not). Really appreciate your helps.

Comment: Do you mean when the Dock has its setting changed (whether it auto-hides or not)? Or do you mean, when it's in auto-hiding mode, you want to detect when it shows itself and when it goes back to hidden?

Comment: Yes, i mean when it's in auto-hiding mode.

Comment: It seems like there's no way to catch that kind of event in Cocoa. I've figured another way out for my problem. Should be closed here.